# Re-sizing the webpage content

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project I have a webpage which has 2 div areas right and left. The left div takes almost 60% of the whole page width and the right one takes around 36% of the page. I wanted to resize the both div areas in a proper ratio when I shrink the browser from the right side or left side. The UI is getting generated from Javascript. This is the code.

```
boardHolderPadding = $board.outerHeight() - $board.height();
$board.height(viewportHeight - siblingsHeight - boardHolderPadding);

this.$('#board .droptarget').setWidthAsRatioOfHeight(this.options.ratio);

$('#sidebar').width($(window).width() - $board.find('#board').width() - 50);
```

I tried with JQuery resize plugin but couldnt get the proper result I'm looking for. Anyone have suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps research into responsive ui using css media query eg http://neevtech.com/blog/2012/05/01/responsive-ui-using-css-media-query/

Comment: @Malvolio, problem is the whole page is getting generated from JS but I love the way if we can do it with CSS, I tried with min-width and max-width still only the right side, the Sidebar is getting shrinked, not the Board

Comment: @ChrisMoutray: The media query is a great way of doing this. But its more suitable if we can get a proper idea of the screen size. If a user resize the browser in normal desktop environment, the page should be response accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in a different way in Javascript and I hope this will help someone to fix if they come across an issue like that

```
relativeSize : function(width, height){
    var boardWidth = this.$("#board").width(),
            boardHeight = this.$("#board").height(), 
            newcard = this.$("#newCard").width(), 
            space = width - boardWidth - newcard;
            ratio = space / width * 3; //used to increment the ratio with 3 as the ratio is very tiny value, this will help to increase minimizing size
            bheight = boardHeight - 25; // used to reduce the height by 25px, u can use any amount to match ur ratio
        var relHeight = (space < ratio) ? bheight : height;
        return relHeight;
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/UrE33) but I think you just need to set your widths as percentages rather than trying to calculate them - note *display* is set to *inline-block*

```
<div>
    <div class="small-left-column">this is the left column</div>
    <div class="large-right-column">this is the right column</div>
</div>

<style>
.small-left-column {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #aeaeae;
    display: inline-block;
}
.large-right-column {
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #aeaeae;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

So I think for your example your would have something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sidebar').addClass('small-left-column');
    $('#board').addClass('large-right-column');
});
```

Comment: Tip: If you need to support IE below 9, add an IE-specific CSS with `.small-left-column, .large-right-column { zoom: 1; display: inline }`. That's IE's proprietary way of saying `inline-block`.

Comment: @StefanMajewsky does it matter which style appears first, in that should the IE specific styling come before or after the `display: inline-block;` styling?

Comment: @ChrisMoutray, Thanks but this approach wont work here as the whole layout is generated using Javascript. I'm looking for a solution using Javascript

Comment: You can continue to generate your layout using JavaScript, just at the end you assign css class styles to the elements. I don't understand why this won't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for the pure-Javascript version of the above:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sidebar').css( {
        width: '30%'
        backgroundColor: '#aeaeae',
        display: 'inline-block'
    });
    $('#board').css({
        width: '60%',
        backgroundColor: '#aeaeae',
        display: 'inline-block'
    });
});
```